# position image at top of cell and on bottom of cell

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm creating a schematic tree of a connection.
I use tables to create it.
The first cell contains a panel. This panel has a color and a number in it. At the right if the panel, in the middle I have a horizontal line of 15px width.
The next cell also a panel like above, but this one also has a horizontal line at the left of also 15px wide.
The next row has a similar panel in the 2nd cell.

```
     ********        ********
-----*      *--------*      *
     ********        ********
                     ********
                 ----*      *
                     ********
```

Now I want the 2nd row to be connected vertically to the one above:

```
     ********        ********
-----*      *--------*      *
     ********    |   ********
                 |   ********
                 ----*      *
                     ********
```

I thought of doing this with an extra column that I give the `background-color` of black and 2px wide.
It looks almost great, but at the top and at the bottom I don't want to see the line for about 10px.
I wanted to place little images here, just a white block to go over the line.

question: How can I place two images in one table cell where one is at the top of the cell and one at the bottom of the cell?

I tried this with css:

```
.imT {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 2px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.imB {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 2px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score -1):

vertical-align would not work for block level element. Thus you need to set `display: inline-block;` and remove the `float:left;`:

```
.imT {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.imB {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 30px;
    width: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Or, you may use `display: table-cell;` instead of inline-block.

Comment: This is not working either. both images stay in the middle of the cell.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Is this class for the image or for a container? Could you add a demo?